# Attributes not showing when element is clicked

Tags: jquery

When each element is clicked, `active-page` (which contains the white background attribute) should be added to their class but it's not doing that.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/sn-tin/pen/xxYQgBo?editors=1111

```js
$(".list-of-pages .pages").click(function(event) {
  console.log(event.target);
  let targetLink = $(event.target);
  if (targetLink.hasClass("project-page")) {
    $(this).addClass("active-page");
    $(".about-me-page").removeClass("active-page");
    $(".contact-page").removeClass("active-page");
  }
  if (targetLink.hasClass("about-me-page")) {
    $(this).addClass("active-page");
    $(".project-page").removeClass("active-page");
    $(".contact-page").removeClass("active-page");
  }
  if (targetLink.hasClass("contact-page")) {
    $(this).addClass("active-page");
    $(".project-page").removeClass("active-page");
    $(".about-me-page").removeClass("active-page");
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: pink;
}

.list-of-pages {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 30px auto 20px;
}

.list-of-pages a {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
}

.list-of-pages a:hover {
  color: gray;
}

.list-of-pages span {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.active-page {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.active-page a {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list-of-pages d-flex flex-row" id="portfolio-pages">
  <div class="pages project-page active-page">
    <a href="#">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-code fa-lg"></i>
      <span>Projects</span>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="pages about-me-page">
    <a href="#">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-user fa-lg"></i>
      <span>About Me</span>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="pages contact-page">
    <a href="#">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-phone fa-lg"></i>
      <span>Contact</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have not imported the jQuery library in your codepen example.

Comment: ...but this is not the root cause, since if I add jQuery to the example it still does not work. The jQuery code is running (I see the result of console.log in the console), so @David IMO it's not a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to do it like this:

```
$(".list-of-pages .pages").click(function(event) {
  console.log(event.target);
  $(".list-of-pages .pages").removeClass("active-page")
  $(this).addClass("active-page")
});
```

Why did your code not work?

It's because you are using `event.target`. that will refer to the element you click on. It could be `.pages` or any of the children of that.

**Demo**

```js
$(".list-of-pages .pages").click(function(event) {
  console.log(event.target);
  $(".list-of-pages .pages").removeClass("active-page")
  $(this).addClass("active-page")
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: pink;
}

.list-of-pages {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 30px auto 20px;
}

.list-of-pages a {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
}

.list-of-pages a:hover {
  color: gray;
}

.list-of-pages span {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.active-page {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  a {
    color: black;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list-of-pages d-flex flex-row" id="portfolio-pages">
  <div class="pages project-page active-page">
    <a href="#">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-code fa-lg"></i>
      <span>Projects</span>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="pages about-me-page">
    <a href="#">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-user fa-lg"></i>
      <span>About Me</span>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="pages contact-page">
    <a href="#">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-phone fa-lg"></i>
      <span>Contact</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".list-of-pages .pages").click(function (event) {    
    $(this).closest(".list-of-pages").find(".pages").removeClass("active-page");
    $(this).addClass("active-page")
});
```

This works even when you apply the `list-of-pages` class to multiple divs in your page